# Can I recieve messages from someone not in my contacts?

Tags: contacts

Am I able to recieve or send text messages from a android user if I don't save their number and my airdrop is turned on to "contacts only"?

Answer (score 2):

AirDrop and text messages have nothing to do with each other.

AirDrop lets you use your iOS device to send or receive files from nearby users who also have iOS devices.

Text messages are just that - text messages. You use the Messages app to send or receive text messages to or from any cell phone number.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Air Drop is a way to share files with people who are nearby.

Text messages are separate. You should receive those from anyone who sends them to you.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think this will work with android users. I believe the only people you can see regardless of what is checked are iOS or OS X users.